# I want to print a list of errors in Show_form () but I can't

Tags: php

show_form does not accept the parameter.
function show_form($erro) {
(____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________)

```
<?php 
//formulário separado por funções
function show_form($erro) {
  if ($erro) {
    implode('<ul><il>', $erro);
    print '</il></ul>';   
  }
    print<<<HTML
         <form method="post" action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]">
         Your name: <input type="text" name="my_name">
         <br>
         <input type="submit" value="Say hello">
        </form>
HTML;
}
function process_form(){
  print "hello, ". $_POST['my_name'];
}
function validate_form() {
  if (strlen($_POST['my_name']) < 3) {
    $erros[] = 'A string tem que ter no minimo 3 caracteres';
  }
  if (! isset($_POST['my_name'])) {
    $erros[] = 'É obrigatório digitar algo';
  }
  if (! is_string($_POST['my_name'])) {
    $erros[] = 'Não é permitido numeros';
  }
  return $erros;
}

if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
  $erros = validate_form();
  if ( validate_form() ) {
    process_form();
  } else {
    show_form($erros);
  }
} else {
  show_form();
}
?>
```

Comment: It's `li`, not `il`...

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of nested functions and just use conditionals...

```
<?php 

$self = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
if (strlen($_POST['my_name']) < 3) {
    $erros = 'A string tem que ter no minimo 3 caracteres';
  } elseif (!isset($_POST['my_name'])) {
    $erros = 'É obrigatório digitar algo';
  } elseif (!is_string($_POST['my_name'])) {
    $erros = 'Não é permitido numeros';
  } else { $erros = "hello, ". $_POST['my_name'];
} 
}

echo $erros;

?>
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]);?>">
         Your name: <input type="text" name="my_name">
         <br>
         <input type="submit" value="Say hello">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
//formulário separado por funções
require 'functions.php';

if ('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
  if ( $erros = validate_form() ) {
    show_form($erros);
  } else {
    process_form();
  }
} else {
  show_form();
}
?>
//////////////
<?php 
function show_form($erro = array()) {
  if ($erro) {
    print "<ul><li>";
    print implode('</li><li>', $erro);
    print '</li></ul>';   
  }
    print<<<HTML
         <form method="post" action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]">
         Your name: <input type="text" name="my_name">
         <br>
         <input type="submit" value="Say hello">
        </form>
HTML;
}
function process_form(){
  print "hello, ". $_POST['my_name'];
}

function validate_form() {
  $erros = array();
  if (strlen($_POST['my_name']) < 3) {
    $erros[] = 'A string tem que ter no minimo 3 caracteres';
  }
  if (strlen($_POST['my_name']) == 0) {
    $erros[] = 'É obrigatório digitar algo';
  }
  return $erros;
}
?>
```